# Hibernate version?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm using [JBoss Embedded](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EmbeddedJBoss) version beta3.SP10 and I'm facing a persistence bug that is should be fixed in some Hibernate version.  Sadly, I don't know what version of Hibernate is used in my JBoss Embedded and couldn't find a way to find this information, the `hibernate-all.jar` bundled in it doesn't contain a  `org.hibernate.Version` class, nor a MANIFEST.

How can I find the currently loaded Hibernate version without using `org.hibernate.Version`?

Comment: What is your use case exactly? Why not using the `Version` class if you have this need?

Comment: Erm my Hibernate distribution doesn't have this class... It seems to have been added in the nearer past.

The use case I have is a bug that I can't figure out: see http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1006411

This is because I use embedded JBoss on Tomcat and this distribution comes with Hibernate whose version I don't know. Chances are a newer version could resolve the issue (I posted a link to a bug report).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this,

```
System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());
```

[found here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1003161)

Answer (score 10):

Another way to obtain the version.

```
System.out.println(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.VERSION)
```

This is for older version of Hibernate. e.g. 3.3.1.GA

Comment: Yes, for earlier ver i.e 3.2.x, only this will work. In earlier ver, Version constant doesn't appear in annotations.common.

Answer (score 6):

This simple Java code is get the Hibernate version.

```
package com.test;
public class TestBean {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String hibernateVersion = org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.VERSION;
        System.out.println("Hibernate Version: "+ hibernateVersion);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Output:** `Hibernate Version: 3.1.0.GA`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it seems hard to find what exact versions of Hibernate modules are used. Some suggestions:

1. <strike>Check if your Hibernate JAR has a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with the version in it.</strike> It looks like the JBoss folks were using Ant at this time and the Manifest doesn't provide the version.
2. Dig the [JBoss Embedded SVN](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EmbeddedFromSVN) to find out what they're doing exactly.
3. Try with [JBoss embedded beta3.SP12](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/embedded/jboss-embedded/beta3.SP12/) (that you can get from the Maven repository).
4. Try to replace the hibernate-all with a bundle containing Hibernate EM 3.4.0.GA.

I would give options 3 and 4 a try.

Comment: I tried this before. No version there. I just found https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1003161&start=0 but I don't know where to put that param. I tried as context param in web.xml, but it doesn't work. BTW JBoss embedded is beta3.SP10, the latest from 2009-09-09.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the way of @Shell, not that of @pudaykiran. Actually, I found these two way get different input in my case.
As said @pudaykiran, I got:

3.2.0 Final

And as @Shell said:

3.5.4 Final

I guess the 3.5.4 final version used `org.hibernate.annotations.common` of previous version. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: FWIW, those different commands returned different results for me as well:

    `System.out.println(org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.VERSION)` returned `13.2.0.Final`, while 
    `System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString())`
returned 

`3.6.10.Final`.  

A newer (5.x) version only worked with the second command; the first one resulted in this exception:
`No such property: VERSION for class: org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version`

Comment: Then I guess the 1st one does not work nowadays.